# bullets not displayed on GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to put bullets on my gsp page and display the list

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${totalCount}" var="cl">
        <g:each in="${cl}" var ="c">
            <li>${c}</li>
        </g:each>       
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

total Count is a list which looks like

```
[{Total_Documents=86, Total_Artifact_Clause=95, Total_Artifact_DefinedTerms=63, Total_Artifact_Title=310, Total_Classifications=44, Total_Unclassified_Artifacts=432} ]
```

There are no bullet displayed only the list is displayed in a straight line

Comment: there is no css on this page

Comment: Yes, there is CSS controlling this. View the HTML source in your browser and you will see it's including a stylesheet or something.

Comment: yes there is.  sorry I was wrong. I got it fixed. thanks

Comment: No worries, you might consider deleting your question since it was such a simple oversight. Otherwise I can add my previous comment as an answer. Up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the "bullets" aren't appearing is because your page is likely including a style sheet that overrides that default behavior. This is common if you are using the default layout and styles provided with Grails.

Check the rendered HTML in your browser to identify what CSS is being included (or check your layout that your GSP is using).